# How to access sliced sprites in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to set the pixels of a tile to the pixels of a sprite. I have a sliced spritesheet called "lofiEnvironment2" in the Resources folder.

I can't drag the child sprites to inspector.

I have tried using Resources.LoadAll that seemed to work for everyone else a few years ago:

```
private Sprite[] sprites;

    void Start()
    {
        sprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("lofiEnvironment2");
        print(sprites.Length); // 0
```

I have no idea what to try anymore. I can't find any solutions to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you should **not** use Resources **at all**! See [Best Practices for the Resources System](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/assets-resources-and-assetbundles#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b5a7).

---

You **could** drag it into the Inspector if you would **not** place it in the `Resources` folder but anywhere else and make your field serialized:

```
 [SerializeField] private Sprite[] sprites;
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't even notice I could drag it to inspector because I was accidentally using Texture2D.

Comment: Should both work actually ;) ou only need to make sure to set your texture's type to `Sprite (2D and UI)`